PYGTK: Referencing an existing object instance from another object?
I am trying to return an instance of an object to another object something like this:
`class object1():
   attrib = '??'
 
   def obj_instance(self):
       return self

class object2():

   obj1 = object1.obj_instance()`

The problem with this is that it needs 'self' declared as a parameter to obj_instance() like this:
obj1 = object1.obj_instance(self) print obj1.attrib    <<<< This fails with object2 has no attribute 'attrib'
If I use:
`class object1():
def obj_instance():      <<<  i.e.,  without 'self'
   return self`

I receive an error of 'self' is not defined.
Obviously these trials have not produced anything useful. I can also not go up the parent tree to get access to object1 (where object2 gets instantiated after object1). From the Python code I have provided it is not obvious why that is the case. Trust me, it is the case.
Is there some way to get a reference whereby the attributes of object1 can be accessed from within object2?
I believe this can be done within C/C++, but it is looking like it is not possible in Python.
Comments?
